# Calculate some math, error "." instead of ","

Tags: c#, string, math

I want to calculate some math in C#, but I have a problem. My numbers are all written with `.` instead of `,`. For example 0.1 instead of 0,1.

```
(2^8 - 1)* 0.1 - 99.9
```

Because all of them are string, I convert them to int.

My code:

```
 String factor = "0.1";
 String offset = "99.9";

 Int64 result = (Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(2, 8) - 1) * Convert.ToInt64(factor.ToString().Replace(".", ","))) + Convert.ToInt64(offset.ToString().Replace(".", ","));
```

I am getting an error: "String not correct format."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

```
var d = double.Parse("0.1",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @LeVietHung `d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: i have smal question, how can i round 99,879999 to 99,88?

Comment: @LeVietHung `double d =  99.879999; var str = Math.Round(d, 2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`